# What am I doing wrong with exporting data from a python program?

Tags: python

I have a inventory program that works. I am trying to save out the data (item names and qty) which are held in a list called inventory. So they can be reused for the next time the program is launched and edited at a later date.

My inventory program code:

```
import os

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = []
        self.qty = []
    def remove(self, name):
        ix = self.item.index(name)
        self.item.pop(ix)
        self.qty.pop(ix)

    def add(self, name, qty):
        self.item.append(name)
        self.qty.append(qty)

    def update(self, name, update):
        if update >= 0:
            self.qty[self.item.index(name)] += update
        elif update <= -1:
            self.qty[self.item.index(name)] += update

    def search(self, name):
        pos = self.item.index(name) if name in self.item else -1
        if pos >= 0:
            return self.item[pos], self.qty[pos]
        else:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        out = ""
        zipo = list(zip(self.item, self.qty))
        for foobar in zipo:
            out += f"Item : {foobar[0]} \nQuantity : {foobar[1]}\n"
            out += "----------\n"
        return out


def menuDisplay():
    """Display the menu"""
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print('(99) Quit')


def add_one_item(inventory):
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
            assert new_name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed!"
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def remove_one_item(inventory):
    print('Removing Inventory')
    print('==================')
    removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
    inventory.remove(removing)


def ask_exit_or_continue():
    return int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))


def update_inventory(inventory):
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
    update = int(input(
        "Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    inventory.update(item, update)


def search_inventory(inventory):
    print('Searching Inventory')
    print('===================')
    search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
    result = inventory.search(search)
    if result is None:
        print("Item not in inventory")
    else:
        name, qty = result
        print('Item:     ', name)
        print('Quantity: ', qty)
        print('----------')


def print_inventory(inventory):
    print('Current Inventory')
    print('=================')
    print(inventory)


def main():
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        try:
            menuDisplay()
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            if CHOICE in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if CHOICE == 1:
                    add_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    remove_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    update_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    search_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print_inventory(inventory)
                exit_choice = ask_exit_or_continue()
                if exit_choice == 99:
                    exit()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

        # If the user pick an invalid choice,
        # the program will come to here and
        # then loop back.


main()
```

The program is called Cleancopy.py and I am trying to save the data to a TextEdit file or excel document called Inventory.

The code that is suppose to export the name and qty in the list called inventory.

How do I fix this? This is my first time trying to save this data. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't a single thing before `import os` and `dictVar = eval(strVar)`? Because if so, then delete it, it may be interfering with it.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson Hmmm...... This is strange. It may be some sort of bug. Try putting it in a new .py file.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson It may be a bug... Try to put your code into a new .py file

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson No, your code is correct, it must be some sort of bug. This is confusing...

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson It isn't a problem with the os library, it's saying there is an error in the typing itself, but it seems to me there is no error in your code. I don't know why its saying that when everything is perfect, I done this same kind of thing myself.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson Try `pip install os`... Tel me if that works

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson I just tried running your code with the same file names, and It shows me an error saying `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    dictVar = eval(strVar)
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson So it isn't a package error. maybe try writing the code differently.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson How about this... explain to me what this program is supposed to do, then we can go from there, I think it would be easier for the both of us.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson Ok I figured it out. where you opened the first file, you gave it a variable named `fptr`. When you closed it, you used `ftpr.clese()` it is supposed to be `fptr.close()`.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson You should use `from Cleancopy import *` instead of opening it. this will import all data from the Cleancopy.py to the main file.

Comment: After doing what you said, it launches the program, but doesn't save the data.

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: @GeorgeDavidson Yes sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224389/discussion-between-sxolarbit-and-george-davidson).